# Using a link with a browser

Tags: google-play-store, email, browser

I have a simple link from an email which I click.

I get the following error message:

```
"to view this content, install and set up a web browsing app."
```

I already set the default browser to once chrome and once firefox, but still I get this error.

What could be the problem ? and hints ?

The link is about testing an app:
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/solveraapps.chronicbrowser_wgd_maps It should derict you to a page for installing the app. You will not be able to install the app, (Because you should be member of an Google+ Group), but at least there should come a different message from a website content.

Comment: When I long press the link and choose the option to open in another tab it opens ! So that's something to do with how it is linked

Comment: Also if I paste the link in Firefox, it opens to Google account sign in. So surely something fishy with the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly copy and paste the link into chrome and stay logged in to your account. Else link looks fine to me.